# R language stream package DFD_window

Tags: r, csv, sliding-window

I want to use "DSC_Window" function for sliding window algorithm, but i don't know how to pass data in this. i have data in ".csv" format.

**I am using "stream" package in R."**

An Example:

`stream <- Pass csv data
window <- DSC_Window(horizon=100)
window
update(window, stream, 200)
window`

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you are using any non-base R package, be sure to explicitly list them in your question.

Comment: Is it okay?? @MrFlick